# small issue in react-native | ActivityIndicator | component | props inside a component | props | setState

Tags: function, react-native, components, state, activity-indicator

so my issue is that i need to set a State inside a function/component.
the State "isLoading" is set to **true** by default (it's for the ActivityIndicator ) and i need to change it back to **false** inside the component so that the **indicator** stops working and the component renders the results.

here is code:

```
const Data = require('../data/my_data.json');

export default class Albums extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Data_list : Data,
      isLoading: true,
    };

componentWillMount() {
    return this.state.Data_list.map(something=> (
      <list_Detail key={something.id} something={something} />
    ));
  }

render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
       return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
           <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
       )
    }
return (
    <ScrollView>{this.componentWillMount()}</ScrollView>

    )}
}
```

i have already tried this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    return this.state.Data_list.map(something=> (
      <list_Detail key={something.id} something={something} />
    ))
    .then(this.setState({isLoading: false}));
  }
```

but it didn't work

SO ANY IDEAS !!!!????

Comment: Why should you use an indicator to import data from a local file?

Comment: i used the indicator because importing data took time (like 3s) so in that 3s i need to show the indicator  so that the user know that something is loading and he just need to wait for it. now in `state`  `isLoading` is set to **true** so the indicator  can show on the screen but after importing all the data i need to set it back to **false**

Comment: @hongdevelop i'm editing my post so that you can understand what exactly i'm struggling with

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillMount` is a lifecycle method, that is called right before the component is rendered. You cannot return UI from this method

Move UI part to `render` method and keep only the api call in `componentWillMount`.

```
componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5d05c8712132b7426d0')
    .then(response => this.setState({Data: response.data, isLoading: false}));
    )); 
}
```

In `render` method,

```
render(){
  return (
  //other UI
  {this.state.Data.map(something => (
          <list_Detail key={something.id} something={something} />
         />
  ))}
}
```

Find the usage for `componentWillMount` and other lifecycle methods [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#commonly-used-lifecycle-methods)

Comment: thank you for answer and explaining that to me, but it works fine just the way it is, but you didn't answer me the real problem that i'm struggling with witch is set the  `isLoading: false` inside this component: 
`componentWillMount() {
    return this.state.Data.map(something=> (
      <list_Detail key={something.id} something={something} />
    ));
  }`

Comment: Why do want to set `isLoading` when you are already setting it to `false` on the API response arrival?

Comment: i need to set `isLoading` to `false` in the second `componentWillMount()`. the one **without** the API response.

Comment: i'm editing my post so that you can understand what exactly i'm struggling with